# How many chapter are stocked by publishers?

Tags: manga-production, mangaka

I was wondering if every mangaka (or prehaps most of them) prepares some chapter beforehand, or if they develop the plot and draw the chapter at a glance, during the week after the last one is released.

I red [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-far-ahead-is-planning-done-before-a-manga-is-released) and the answer with lowest score is very nice, but without a link is not possible to define it credible (with respect of the author).

Maybe Shonen Jump (and other magazine) require an amount of chapters beforehand, in order to be "safe" in case of something happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the answer in the previous question said, mangakas are ahead of 3-4 chapters though this figure may vary in some cases. The credible source for this is Eiichiro Oda, creator of One Piece manga, answers his fans questions at the [SBS Corner](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS), here's what he had said about this in particular:

> **D:** When an artist is drawing for example, Chapter 10, what chapter is
> being printed in the newest Weekly Jump?
>
> **O:** I see. I wondered about
> this myself, years ago. So I understand your curiosity. At this EXACT
> moment, Issue 46 of Jump is hitting the stands. It contains One Piece
> Chapter 60, "Solution". But I have finished the drafts up through
> Chapter 63, "I Ain't Gonna Die". So a chapter comes out roughly 3
> weeks after I finish it. But that's only my CURRENT schedule. Not all
> people drawing weekly serials have the same system. I could change if
> need be. There are various cases.*[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_6#Chapter_46.2C_Page_46)*

And for your other question of how far ahead the mangaka develops the plot, Hiro Mashima, the mangaka of Fairy Tail says:

> **Q:** How far in advance do you create your stories (before they're
> published in Shonen Magazine)?
>
> **Hiro Mashima:** Generally speaking, I tend to think of the next episode
> as I'm creating the current one. Sometimes I get writers block.
> Sometimes inspiration just comes when you're sitting down at the
> toilet. I like to think of that as just an inspiration from heaven.
> (laughs)
> *[Source](http://manga.about.com/od/mangaartistinterviews/a/HiroMashima_2.htm)*

Other references:

- [Yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100616163109AAa8QF7)
- [Insight on how mangas are created and typical schedule of mangakas](http://prezi.com/rzguglly4gg8/what-is-the-process-of-how-manga-comics-are-made/)

Comment: @JaAd You're welcome desu~

Comment: This answer (generally) also applies to just about every form of serialized entertainment: TV shows, newspaper comics, etc. The writer(s)/artist(s)/actor(s)/etc. create serials in advance of what's available to the public. How far in advance depends on the media and production group/individual in question, but it happens everywhere.

Comment: @BrianS i agree. I thought that mangaka are from another universe, especially Oda ;-) .